# Should I use webRTC or socket.io for a text chat?

Tags: websocket, socket.io, webrtc

I'm working on a node project and want to create a text chat between multiple users. So, more than 2 users in the chat.

I can't seem to figure out what approach is best: using socket.io (example of a text chat right here: https://socket.io/get-started/chat/ or webRTC. When I try to look for a webRTC example of text chat, I find links to video chat or a 1-1 text chat which uses sockets.

Which one should I use for a text chat?

Answer (score 1):

WebRTC is a point 2 point link (although it can go through server). If you want multiple users on single chat, WebSockets might be the right approach for you. With WebRTC you might need to create a link between each 2 users, and that is a pain.
Anyway, if you use Azure maybe SignalR Service is the right answer, depending on you scalability needs.

Answer (score 1):

[WebRTC](https://webrtc.org/) is [Peer-to-Peer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peer-to-peer) and is mainly emphasized on video/audio streaming. It can be used for multiple users, but that would result in a complicated structure like [mesh structure](https://webrtcglossary.com/mesh/). Based on your situation, I would recommend a simpler server-based solution, for example, the one you mentioned: [Socket.io](http://socket.io).

It's completely possible to implement what you said with WebRTC, but it would be complicated and not very suitable for your situation (text-only).

I recommend you to look more into WebRTC if you are still interested in it,  it's great but it doesn't fit your current need very well.